Fine-tuning llama 3.1 for Farsi
So far I've played around with llama 3.1 using ollama and open web ui. They perform fantastic in English but for Farsi the outputs are nearly gibberish. Sometimes it spits out words in other languages as well which I suspect is because of a lack of enough Farsi tokens. I've looked up for ways of fine-tuning already existing LLMs and it seems like the easiest method is to use something called axolotl, but I cannot figure out how to use it with the limited number of datasets available for Farsi. This is the most comprehensive list for Farsi NLP datasets, and it's limited, the best one that I could find suitable for this task was PersianQA. Upon inspecting the yaml file for axolotl configuration, I see the following:
type: alpaca # format | format:<prompt_style> (chat/instruct) | <prompt_strategies>.load_<load_fn>

under the datasets entry. This is apparently the format of the prompts in the dataset. I couldn't find any further documentation about what any of the types were and how to use them. [alpaca, sharegpt, gpteacher, oasst, reflection]
The questions that I have:

Is it a good idea to use a dataset such as PersianQA to finetune a chatbot?
What does dataset type mean in axolotl? I've searched a lot and couldn't find anything.
Is what I'm doing generally correct? Or using something like hugging face library would be better for my case?

